# Invalid XML in file view.xml

Tags: xml

I'm getting this error in my store:

**Invalid XML in file /Library/WebServer/Documents/Magento/app/design/frontend/vendor/vendor_theme/etc/view.xml:
Element 'theme': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
Line: 2**

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     &#60;title&#62;Vendor&#60;/title&#62;
     &#60;parent&#62;Magento/blank&#60;/parent&#62;
 &#60;/theme&#62;
```

I've run this through xml check sites. It's valid according to them and my knowledge of XML.

I'm new to this framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
     <title>Vendor</title>   <parent>Magento/blank</parent> 
</view>
```

There is have to **view** not **theme**

Comment: Thank you! Thank worked. You rock my friend. Damn this is one problematic framework.